# How to ignore <p> CSS rules in wordpress theme?

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm editing the stylesheet of my Wordpress blog. I've installed a theme that's otherwise pretty cool, but its styling of blockquotes is very ugly.

I can edit the appearance of the `<blockquote></blockquote>` object just fine. The problem is that the paragraph that I put in between those quotes is also assigned `<p></p>` tags by Wordpress, and those also take properties from the stylesheet. The theme has very intricate styling for the `<p>` tag, and because of that, those take priority over the things I'm trying to make it do.

Sample code:

```
<p>Text here</p>
<blockquote><p>Quote here</p></blockquote>
<p>More text</p>
```

Sample CSS:

```
blockquote {
   /* styling here */
}
blockquote p {
   /* whatever I put here is overwritten by other stylesheet rules */
}
.post-video .video-div p {
   /* stylesheet from my theme that has more levels than my own added style rules, so takes priority */
}
```

Basically, the `.post-video .video-div p` rules overwrite my own `blockquote p` rules, so I can't change the appearance. I also don't really want to mess with all those theme-specified classes. I know I could write `.post-video .video-div blockquote p` and be more important than the standard rules, but I don't know what those classes do and would rather not mess with them.

Any suggestions how to solve this?

Comment: I think you'd want to look at [wpautop](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wpautop)

Comment: are you able to add an id anywhere? say wrap it around the bit where that bllockquote is?  Basically, you need to make your selector more specific than the `.post-video .video-div` selector

Comment: Have a read of this: https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2007/07/css-specificity-things-you-should-know/ it may help you

Comment: Do you have try to use !importnat, like margin:0px!importnat;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use !important after your styling.

```
blockquote p {
   background: red !important;
}
```

!important will force the browser to honor your CSS and use it over any other CSS written for that element.

Comment: This worked. I clearly should've spent more time googling the answer; thanks nevertheless!